# What is the best method to store data on Apple Watch

Tags: core-data, swift2, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I'm programming an App which needs to store data to files (or any non-volatile method). I also have to say NSUserDefaults is not a good idea for my case since I'm storing arrays of structs. I also tried storing it with C's fwrite() but this options seems very inefficient. So my questions is now: How can I efficiently store data to Apple Watch's storage with Swift

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Core Data is the persistence engine of choice for complex data structures.  It is integrated into Apple's other frameworks and is under active development and is mature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) like you would in a iOS App. Or you could try [Realm](https://realm.io/) which I find a lot easier to use.